# Facebook Graph API/ PHP SDK Login ISSUE

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

Cannot open My application, 
I am a newbie to Facebook Application Development
I simply want to fetch user name of logged user and display it
but i cannot login and i always get error messages

this is the simple code copied for developer.facebook.com

I also tried specifying permission and redirect url, but still its of no use
PLEASE HELP OUT, i have been stuck for past two days

here is the code for PHP page

```
<?
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('src/facebook.php');

  config = array(
    'appId' => '***',
    'secret' => '***',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $standalone_url = 'http://localhost/trial/';
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'next' => $standalone_url.'next.php', 
                'redirect_uri' =>  $standalone_url.'message.php',
        'scope' => 'user_about_me'));
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

i have tried/ already

a) Cleared all Web cache n history(web Browser: Firefox)

b) also deleted java applets and application CACHE

Please See the image in URL
to get more clear picture

[trial](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/5719/trialux.jpg)

[error](http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/9302/errorpg.jpg)

Comment: I highly recommend immediately changing your secret key via Developer application cause one you posted will be preserved in revisions history)!

Comment: ok, i deleted the facebook application
please tell now how to
create a login for my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In image you share your redirect uri is: `http://localhost/trial/index.php`
which does not match your canvas uri in your configuration panel: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps`

So solution is: your redirect must exactly match with `canvas url` even trailing slash:
http://my_app.com/

Comment: please tell where to refer
i am completely new to facebook app development and have no idea about where to begin, developer.facebook does not help in anyway


1) i am working on php
2) i want to develop a application which will run on canvas
3) please tell/guide each n every process for developing with proper Oauth 2.0 with php not FQL, cause i read that its not much useful or such

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you:
http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/

Or you can try this. It uses PHP SDk v 4.0:
http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-login-with-facebook-using-sdk-4-in-php_661.html